# Asymptotic expansion of integral involving Bessel Function and Logarithm

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, special-functions, bessel-functions

I would like to obtain the asymptotic expression for $b \rightarrow \infty$ of the following integral

$$
\tag 1
I = \int_0^1 dx \ln(x) \frac{x}{x^4+a^2} J_0(bx),
$$

where $a$ is a real constant and $J_0$ is the Bessel function of order 0. From numerical analysis, the integral seems to be governed by small $x$, so I believe that taking $1 \rightarrow \infty$ in the upper bound should be a valid approximation.

I tried extending the integral to the complex plane, and also deriving with respect to $b$ to try to find a differential equation for $I$ but none of these approaches seem to work.

Any idea about how to tackle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: Thanks to a nice comment by @Maxim, a correction of the answer is made to take into account (a typo and) the contribution of the region $x>1$ to the asymptotic behavior of the integral for $b\to\infty$.

Decomposing the integral as
\begin{align}
I&=I_0-I_1\\
&=\int_0^\infty \ln(x) \frac{x}{x^4+a^2} J_0(bx)\,dx-\int_1^\infty \ln(x) \frac{x}{x^4+a^2} J_0(bx)\,dx
\end{align}
As remarked in the OP, it will be shown that the main asymptotic behavior of the integral is given by $I_0$.
\begin{align}
I_0&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\ln(x^2) \frac{x}{x^4+a^2} J_0(bx)\,dx
\end{align}
Under this form, we can use the [Gabutti and Lepora result](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042787901890) which states that, under rather mild conditions, the Hankel transform of an even function
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}^{(\nu)}\left[\omega,f\right]=\int_0^\infty J_\nu(\omega x)f(x^2)x^{\nu+1}\,dx
\end{equation}
can be written as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}^{(\nu)}\left[\omega,f\right]=\frac{\omega^\nu}{2^{\nu+1}}\int_0^\infty \exp\left( -\frac{\omega^2}{4t} \right)F(t)t^{-\nu-1}\,dt
\end{equation}
when
\begin{equation}
f(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}F(t)\,dt
\end{equation}
i.e. $F(.)$ is the inverse Laplace transform of $f(.)$.

Here, with $\nu=0, \omega=b$, we take $f(s)=\frac{\ln s}{s^2+a^2}$ to write
\begin{equation}
I_0= \frac{1}{4a}\int_0^\infty \exp\left( -\frac{b^2}{4t} \right)F(t)\frac{dt}{t}
\end{equation}
where (see, for example, Ederlyi TI, 5.7.6 p.251)
\begin{equation}
F(t)=\cos (at)\operatorname{Si}(at)+\sin (at)\left[\ln a-\operatorname{Ci}(at)\right]
\end{equation}
when $b\to \infty$ the main contribution of the integral comes from the values of $t\to\infty$, where ([DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12.ii)),
\begin{equation}
F(t)\sim \frac{\pi}{2}\cos(at)+\sin(at)\ln a-\frac{1}{at}\left( 1-\frac{2!}{a^2t^2}+\frac{4!}{a^4t^4}-\frac{6!}{a^6t^6}+\cdots \right)
\end{equation}
this expansion can be integrated term by term. For the first two terms,
\begin{align}
K&=\int_0^\infty \exp\left( -\frac{b^2}{4t} \right)\exp(iat)\frac{dt}{t}\\
&=\int_0^\infty \exp\left( -\frac{b}{4}\left(u-\frac{4ia}{u} \right) \right)\frac{du}{u}\\
&=2K_0(b\sqrt{ a}e^{-i\pi/4})\\
&=2\operatorname{ker}(b\sqrt{a})-2i\operatorname{kei}(b\sqrt{a})
\end{align}
where an integral representation of the modified Bessel function was used (G&R 8.432.7) as well as the Kelvin functions $\operatorname{ker}$ and $\operatorname{kei}$ (G&R 8.8.567.2). The saddle point method shows that this term exponentially decreases when $b\sqrt{a}\gg1$.

The contributions of the other terms can be evaluated using
\begin{align}
Q_n&=\int_0^\infty \exp\left( -\frac{b^2}{4t} \right)\frac{dt}{t^{n+1}}\\
&=\int_0^\infty \exp\left( -\frac{b^2}{4}u \right)u^{n-1}\,du\\
&=\Gamma(n)\left( \frac{2}{b} \right)^{2n}
\end{align}
We obtain thus
\begin{equation}
I_0\sim \frac{1}{4a}\left( \pi\operatorname{ker}(b\sqrt{a})-2\ln (a)\operatorname{kei}(b\sqrt{a})-\frac{(0!)^22^2}{ab^2}+\frac{(2!)^22^6}{a^3b^6}-\frac{(4!)^22^{10}}{a^5b^{10}}+\cdots \right)
\end{equation}
We can also use the asymptotic approximations for the Kelvin functions (G&R 8.566),
\begin{align}
\operatorname{ker}(z)&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2z}}e^{\alpha(-z)}\cos(\beta(-z))\\
\operatorname{kei}(z)&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2z}}e^{\alpha(-z)}\sin(\beta(-z))\\
\alpha(z)&\sim \frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{8z\sqrt{2}}+\ldots\\
\beta(z)&\sim \frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{1}{8z\sqrt{2}}+\ldots\\
\end{align}
For sufficiently large values of $b\sqrt{a}$, the contribution of the Kelvin functions can be neglected.
\begin{equation}
I_0=-\frac{1}{a^2b^2}+O\left(\frac1{b^6}\right) 
\end{equation}
To evaluate $I_1$, one use IBP twice, by remarking that $\int xJ_0( bx)\,dx=b^{-1}xJ_1(bx)$ and $\int J_1( bx)\,dx=-b^{-1}J_0(bx)$. One obains then
$$I_1=-\frac{J_0(b)}{b^2(1+a^2)}+O\left(\frac1{b^3}\right) $$
Thus
$$ I=-\frac{1}{a^2b^2}+\frac{J_0(b)}{b^2(1+a^2)}+O\left(\frac1{b^3}\right)$$
Keeping the first term only, we find $\ln(-I)\simeq -2\ln(b)-2\ln(a)$. With $b=10^k$, this explains the result proposed by @Claude Leibovici : $\gamma=-\ln(100)$ (and also the order of magnitude of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, through a linear regression over the values of $1<a<10$).

Comment: Nice answer ! Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks Claude. Cheers!

Comment: Incredible effort! Thank you both

Comment: There is a typo in the last formula, multiplying by $1/(4 a)$ gives $I \sim -1/(a^2 b^2)$, which can also be derived by first writing the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ as
$$\frac {\ln a} {8 a} G_{0, 4}^{3, 0} {\left(
  z \middle| {- \atop 0, \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2, 0} \right)} -
 \frac \pi {16 a} G_{1, 5}^{3, 1} {\left(
  z \middle| {\frac 1 2 \atop \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2, 0, 0} \right)},$$
where $z = a^2 b^4/256$. The subsequent terms are not correct though, because the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ is $J_2(b)/((a^2 + 1) b^2) + O(b^{-3})$, which can be shown by repeated IBP.

Comment: Thank you very much @Maxim for spotting the error and for proposing another method.

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to do almost anything of potential interest; so, to (may be) get some idea, I considered *numerically* the behaviour of the integral
$$I_{a,k} = \int_0^1 \frac{x \log(x)}{x^4+a^2}\, J_0(10^k\,x)\,dx$$ for $(a=1,2,\cdots,10)$ and  $(k=1,2,\cdots,10)$ and after a few graphical attempts decided to look at the behaviour of $\log(-I_{a,k})$ which, at least, seems to be linearly dependent on $k$ for a given $a$ (with a slope almost independent on the value of $a$).

So, I considered the complete bilinear model
$$\log(-I_{a,k})=\alpha + \beta \,a + \gamma\, k +\delta \,a\,k$$ The result of the first regression $(R^2=0.999795)$ are
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval}
   \\
 \alpha  & -0.59129 & 0.21257 & \{-1.0133,-0.1693\} \\
 \beta   & -0.45739 & 0.03426 & \{-0.5254,-0.3894\} \\
 \gamma  & -4.53646 & 0.03426 & \{-4.6045,-4.4684\} \\
 \delta  & -0.00047 & 0.00552 & \{-0.0114,+0.0105\} \\
\end{array}$$

As expected from the previous remark, the cross parameter $\delta$ is no significant. Repeating the calculations without it, the following results $(R^2=0.999795)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval}
   \\
 \alpha  & -0.57699 & 0.13150 & \{-0.83805,-0.31593\} \\
 \beta   & -0.45999 & 0.01586 & \{-0.49147,-0.42850\} \\
 \gamma  & -4.53906 & 0.01586 & \{-4.57055,-4.50757\} 
\end{array}$$ which basically divide by a factor of $2$ the previous standard errors.

At this point, being very cautious, it *seems* that $\gamma \sim -\log(100)$ and $\beta \sim -\frac 1 {10}\log(100)$